# Mate. Purple icons after reboot

Tags: drivers, 16.04, desktop-environments, mesa

I got strange problem:
Icons in mate got purpled:
[image]

In mate Appearance changing desktop style does not affect icons.

How can i get normal colors back?

**UPD**
Same happens in guest session.
With all sets of icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw same problem after update on other computer.
After some checks i noticed that both computers got video driver update via oibaf driver.

Removing this ppa restored color of icons.

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers && sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe resetting the panel will bring back the default configuration for the panel. At the terminal type `mate-panel --reset`. Hope this help.

Comment: No. it doesen't helped.

Comment: Try this: `mate-panel --reset --layout ubuntu-mate-indicators` in the terminal.

Comment: It doesn't helped too. In guest session i see same pink icons.